# About Mean Value Property of Harmonic Function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I know the question may seem foolish to you but I am not quite sure how to show it in a decent way. My problem is to show that for bounded Borel measurable $f:\mathbb{D}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, (D1) is equivalent to (D2).

(D1) for all sphere $S(x,r)\subset \mathbb{D}^2$, where $S(x,r):=\{y \in \mathbb{D}^2|d(y,x)=r\}$, we have
$$f(x)={1 \over {2\pi r}}\int_{S(x,r)}f(y)\ d\sigma(y)$$
Here $d\sigma$ is the surface measure on $S(x,r)$.

(D2) for all ball $B(x,r)\subset \mathbb{D}^2$, where $B(x,r):=\{y \in \mathbb{D}^2|d(y,x)\leq r\}$, we have
$$f(x)={1 \over {\pi r^2}}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)\ dy$$

I recognize that (D2) is equaivalent to the fact that $f$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D}^2$, but I just have no idea of how to show the seemingly easier part as stated.

Comment: From the domain of the Integral I would at first guess it is Gauß Theorem to swap between a surface integral to a volume integral. But there you would need the divergence

Comment: Jupp it is just Gauß theorem and notice that $\nabla \operatorname{div} = \Delta$ and from the harmonic function it is zero I think I will write an answer for $n$ dimensions

Comment: I tried Gauss theorem, but from (D1) to (D2) I have to show $f$ is at least $C^2$ which is...kind of trouble. Anyway now got a solution by simple calculation!

Comment: how do you define harmonic if $f$ is not $C^2$ ?

Comment: $f$ is now taken from the set of all bounded Borel functions, so from (D2) to (D1) there is no problem about differentiability, but the converse seems to require extra work about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (D1) holds for any $(x,r)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
 \frac 1{\pi r^2} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y)  \, dy 
   &= \frac 1{\pi r^2} \int_0^r \int_{S(x,s)} f(y) \, d\sigma(y)\, ds\\
   &= \frac 1{\pi r^2} \int_0^r 2\pi s f(x)\, ds\\
   &= \frac 2{r^2} f(x) \cdot \int_0^r s\, ds\\
   &= f(x). 
\end{align*}
On the other hand, if (D2) holds, we have
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \frac 1{\pi r^2}\int_{B(x,r)} f(y)\, dy\\
       &= \frac 1{\pi r^2} \int_0^r \int_{S(x,s)} f(y) \, d\sigma(y)\, ds\\
\end{align*}
Differentiating with respect to $r$, we get
$$ 0 = -\frac 2{\pi r^3} \int_0^r\int_{S(x,s)} f(y)\, d\sigma(y)\, ds + \frac 1{\pi r^2} \int_{S(x,r)} f(y)\, d\sigma(y). $$
Or 
$$ \frac 2{\pi r^3} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y)\, dy = \frac 1{\pi r^2}\int_{S(x,r)} f(y)\, d\sigma(y) \iff \frac 1{2\pi r}\int_{S(x,r)} f(y) \, d\sigma(y) = f(x). $$

Comment: I was always considerring by first showing from (D2) that $f$ is harmonic, which implies (D1) by using fundamental solution of Laplace equation, but got stuck at the converse. Thank you for such a clear solution!